# MVC4 EF Foreign Key Association causes invalid ModelState

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-key-relationship

Using EF with MVC4 allows you to specify the inclusion of Foreign Key columns in the model. While this not normally part of *OR* modeling, it does allow MVC4 to automatically generate views with dropdown lists, for the foreign key relationships, when you generate a controller with the `MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework` option.

I have hit a problem creating an object in this scenario.

### Greatly simplified, the models in question are:

**Questionnaire:**

- QuestionnaireID: PK
- CandidateId: FK
- Candidate: Associated object

**Candidate:**

- CandidateID: PK
- Name: string

The problem I have hit is that on a Create view post-back to create a new Questionnaire `ModelState.IsValid` is false. On investigation the error listed is `The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Data.Candidate' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.`

ModelState.Keys includes `Questionnaire.Candidate` as well as `Questionnaire.CandidateId` (which is valid).

I am sure this is something simple, but would like to hear some solutions. The viewbag only has a set for the drop-down list and the view has an @model of type `@model Data.Questionnaire`. There are no editor fields bound to `Questionnaire.Candidate.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have no idea why the built-in EF models do not like the MVC generated scaffolding, for Create postbacks with foreign key columns enabled, I have reverted to what is a more secure solution (still happy to hear why it fails out-of-the-box):

### Create individual view models for specific sensitive operations like create

The theory goes that there are a number of problems using EF domain entities as viewmodels including:

- They potentially expose too much information or allow additional fields  to be posted back
- Validation text is an interface concern and should not be part of a the data model (they actually suggest even the viewmodel is not the place for this text, but I digress).

So basically I now have a CreateCandidateQuestionnaireVM class with only the required fields for selecting appropriate values for a new instance.